# Roses in clay pot started to go bald

Tags: diagnosis, container-gardening, roses

I purchased some roses in clay pots. They were very fresh and beautiful but after a while they were starting to go bald and their leaves turned yellow. What should I do?

They are in open air and have 6 hours per day direct sunlight. They are watered once a day. The temperature is about 28 to 38 degree of Centigrade.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like garden soil in those pots.  Were these roses transplanted from the garden into pots using garden soil?  What about fertilizer?  Looks like a lot of clay, can't really tell, but watering every day is probably too much.  Gotta have proper chemicals with which to do photosynthesis or death.  What is the difference between the three dying or dead roses and the one on the far left?  Anything you are able to come up with would be helpful.  How long have these roses been in these pots, how long were they in the garden if they were in the garden originally?

Comment: Cut those flowers off as soon as possible.  All that energy going into making seed could be better used in the plant itself.  Get rid of the dried and even buds until we can better know what the factors truly are.

Comment: I purchased them about 1 month ago. I don't know about their fertilizer.

Comment: too hot and roses love deep pots- deeper the better and less watering, to stop anything else going wrong remove all dead material from this situation and dead head them too, feed often (rose feed bought at any supermarket) and try to moisten the air around them on a very hot day! the top photo show signs of scorch, if you notice the one in the big pot is doing very well- so put the others if their still alive in a bigger pot! and stand the pots in trays. this will help add moisture to the surrounding air and the plants will let you know when to water again when their dry.

Comment: Hi Arash Mousavi! Are you able or willing to write an answer for this? Did you find out the problem or have a solution? It's in the unanswered questions list, but it's a good question and it would be great if we could get an answer! If not, that's no problem, I just thought I'd ask!

Answer (score 1):

> "Looks like garden soil in those pots. ... Looks like a lot of clay, can't really tell, but watering every day is probably too much. Gotta have proper chemicals with which to do photosynthesis or death."
>
> "Cut those flowers off as soon as possible. All that energy going into making seed could be better used in the plant itself. Get rid of the dried and even buds until we can better know what the factors truly are."
>
> ~stormy

---

> "Too hot and roses love deep pots- deeper the better and less watering, to stop anything else going wrong remove all dead material from this situation and dead head them too, feed often (rose feed bought at any supermarket) and try to moisten the air around them on a very hot day! The top photo show signs of scorch, if you notice the one in the big pot is doing very well- so put the others if their still alive in a bigger pot! And stand the pots in trays. This will help add moisture to the surrounding air and the plants will let you know when to water again when they're dry."
>
> ~olantigh